# How to avoid DDMS conflicts?

Tags: android, ddms

I regularly switch between eclipse/ADT and Android Studio. But I find I always have to *close* one in order to use the other due to DDMS complaining that it is already in use. Is there a way I can work in both without having to close down IDE's all the time?